# What's a good way to use credentials returned by `aws sts assume-role` in current shell session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

`aws sts assume-role` returns credentials in Json-format. Is there an easy way (like putting them in environment variables) so that subsequent calls to `aws` can use them?

Basically, I want something like `sudo -i` for AWS.

Note: I am currently doing this on my laptop with current credentials in env-variables, but it would be nice if the solution also worked on EC2 instances where the original role credentials come from instance-metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the `sts assume-role` command explicitly, you can configure a *profile* that assumes a specific role which is then cached in the CLI. This is [well documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html), but you basically just set it up as an ordinary profile in your `~/aws/config` file, like this:

```
[profile marketingadmin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/marketingadmin
source_profile = default
```

If you enforce MFA when assuming a role (which I strongly recommend that you do), it would look something like this:

```
[profile marketingadmin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/marketingadmin
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:mfa/jonsmith
```

To use the role you set up, you either provide the `--profile` CLI option or make sure to set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable with the profile name.

You could of course also call the `sts assume-role` command explicitly, then you would need to parse out the appropriate values and put them in to the following environment variables: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`.